# Boundaries of connected components

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $ K \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ a compact set and $L_i$  the connected components of $\mathbb{R}^{n} \backslash K$.

I can't see why $\partial L_i \subset K$.

Comment: What’s your definition of the boundary?

Comment: Why there must be a bounded connected component? What if $K=\{0\}$? It seems like this question misses details (I vote to close)

Comment: @Yanko In your case, the boundary of the empty set is empty, and thus is contained within $K$. I agree that the question is missing context, but only in the sense that OP hasn’t added their own effort — the question seems well defined to me.

Comment: @Yanko If $K=\{0\}$ then its complement is connected and so the boundary of the only connected component of the complement is indeed $\{0\}$ as required.

Comment: I see, thanks Santana and Henno.

Answer (score 0):

I’ll assume that $\partial A$ denotes a boundary of a set $A$. The claim can be proved assuming only closedness of the set $K$ in $\Bbb R^n$. Let $x$ be any point of any $\partial L_i$. If $x\in K$, we are done. Otherwise there exists (a unique) $L_j$ containing $x$. Since $L_j$ is an open subset of the space $\Bbb R^n\setminus K$ there exists a open subset $U$ of $\Bbb R^n$ such that $U\cap (\Bbb R^n\setminus K)=U\setminus K=L_j$. Thus $U$ intersects only $L_j$ among $L_k$’s, so $L_i=L_j$. Let $V\subset U$ be any neighborhood of the point $x$. Since $x\in \partial L_i$, $\varnothing\ne V\cap (\Bbb R^n\setminus L_i)\subset V\cap K$. That is $x\in\overline{K}=K$.